# Return diagonal elements of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, diagonal

Given a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, is there a quick way to return the elements on the diagonal?

The reason I would like to do this is to compute `inv(D) A`, where `D` is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries agree with `A` (`A` is my sparse matrix, guaranteed to have nonzeros on the diagonal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [csr_matrix.diagonal()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.diagonal.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.diagonal):

> Returns the main diagonal of the matrix

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
>>> mymat = csr_matrix((4, 4), dtype=np.int8)
>>> mymat.diagonal()
array([0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: *sigh*. When you fail completely at googling :-) Thank you for the answer! +1 (will accept after the 10 minute lockout)

Comment: In your example `mymat` is a dense array (that `toarray()` :)  ).  The sparse diagonal isn't quite a general as the dense one.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the suggestion. I updated the post with Warren's suggestion. Hope you both guys will like my answer now! :) By the way, I got driven by the ref, but what you say makes sense.